# Duplicate existing Power BI page and change data source to a different query

Tags: powerbi

We have a number of different business units each managing their own separate (but consistent) data sets in separate Excel spreadsheets. I've created a multi page pbix file that has queries looking at one of those spreadsheets and the users are happy with how it all looks.

What I'd like to be able to do, now the design is accepted, is to duplicate the existing pages and change the data source (on just the duplicate pages not all of them) to the other spreadsheets without having to rebuild all the graphs and apply all the formatting etc again from scratch.

Is this possible? and if not what would be the best approach, save as new pbix, change queries, then merge everything as a dashboard?

I'm relatively new to Power BI so still wrapping my head around how best to structure things.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of experimentation the simplest route I found was:

1. Added an extra column in the source data for Business Unit
2. Create queries for each Excel file
3. Create an append query pulling all the queries together
4. Built out the charts etc using the append query
5. Duplicated the page so there was one for each business unit
6. Then went back through each page and used a Page Level Filter using the Business Unit column to filter back to the required business unit

It definitely pays off to plan your structure in advance (if you can) as it saves a lot of rework!